# Unable start activity from fragment

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an app using the Cloud Firestore and Kotlin. When I click the login button, it will jump to the dashboard activity which has homeFragment, search fragment, and settingsFragment. In the settingsFragment, there has an edit button to let the user edit their profile. But when I click the edit button, the program will crash. Could you please help me to solve the issue?

Error Message

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.spaceus, PID: 14094
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.spaceus/com.example.spaceus.ui.activities.UserProfileActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mUserDetails has not been initialized
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mUserDetails has not been initialized
    at com.example.spaceus.ui.activities.UserProfileActivity.onCreate(UserProfileActivity.kt:41)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

SettingsFragment.kt

```
class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {

private var _binding: FragmentSettingsBinding? = null
private lateinit var mUserDetails: User
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    //notificationsViewModel =ViewModelProvider(this).get(NotificationsViewModel::class.java)

    _binding = FragmentSettingsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val root: View = binding.root

    val sharedPreferences = this.requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(Constants.MYSHOPPAL_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    //val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.MYSHOPPAL_PREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    val username = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.LOGGED_IN_USERNAME,"")!!
    val email = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.EMAIL,"")!!
    //GlideLoader(this).loadUserPicture(mUserDetails.image.toUri(),iv_user_photo)
    root.tv_username.text = "$username"
    root.tv_email.text = "$email"



    root.btn_logout.setOnClickListener {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
        val intent = Intent(requireContext(), LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Logout Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    root.iv_edit.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(requireContext(), UserProfileActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    return root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

}

UserProfileActivity.kt

```
class UserProfileActivity : BaseActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

private lateinit var mUserDetails: User
private var mSelectedImageFileUri: Uri? =null
private var mUserProfileImageURL: String =""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile)

    if(intent.hasExtra(Constants.EXTRA_USER_DETAILS)){
        //Get the user details from instant as a ParcelableExtra.
        mUserDetails = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.EXTRA_USER_DETAILS)!!
    }


    et_usernameProfile.isEnabled=false
    et_usernameProfile.setText(mUserDetails.username)

    et_emailProfile.isEnabled=false
    et_emailProfile.setText(mUserDetails.email)

    GlideLoader(this@UserProfileActivity).loadUserPicture(mUserDetails.image.toUri(),iv_user_photo)

    iv_user_photo.setOnClickListener(this@UserProfileActivity)
    btn_save.setOnClickListener(this@UserProfileActivity)
    btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(this@UserProfileActivity)
}


override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    if(v != null){
        when (v.id){
            R.id.iv_user_photo ->{
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    //showErrorSnackBar("You already have the storage permission.",false)
                    Constants.showImageChooser(this)
                }else{
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),Constants.READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE)
                }
            }

            R.id.btn_save ->{

                if(validateUserProfileDetails()){

                    showProgressDialog("Please Wait ...")

                    if(mSelectedImageFileUri!=null)
                        FirestoreClass().uploadImageToCloudStorage(this,mSelectedImageFileUri)
                    else{
                        updateUserProfileDetails()
                    }
                }
            }

            R.id.btn_cancel ->{
                val intent = Intent(this@UserProfileActivity, DashboardActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun updateUserProfileDetails(){
    val userHashMap =HashMap<String,Any>()

    val mobileNumber = et_phoneProfile.text.toString().trim{it <= ' '}

    val gender = if(rb_male.isChecked){
        Constants.MALE
    }else{
        Constants.FEMALE
    }

    if(mUserProfileImageURL.isNotEmpty()){
        userHashMap[Constants.IMAGE] = mUserProfileImageURL
    }

    if(mobileNumber.isNotEmpty()){
        userHashMap[Constants.MOBILE]=mobileNumber
    }

    userHashMap[Constants.GENDER]= gender

    userHashMap[Constants.COMPLETE_PROFILE] = 1

    FirestoreClass().updateUserProfileData(this,userHashMap)
}

fun userProfileUpdateSuccess(){
    hideProgressDialog()
    Toast.makeText(this@UserProfileActivity,resources.getString(R.string.msg_profile_update_success),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    startActivity(Intent(this@UserProfileActivity, DashboardActivity::class.java))
    finish()
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode:Int,permissions:Array<out String>,grantResults:IntArray){
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults)

    if(requestCode == Constants.READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE){

        if(grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //showErrorSnackBar("The storage permission is granted.",false)
            Constants.showImageChooser(this)
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,resources.getString(R.string.read_storage_permission_denied),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == Constants.PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE){
            if(data !=null){
                try{
                    //the uri of selected image from photo storage
                    mSelectedImageFileUri= data.data!!
                    GlideLoader(this).loadUserPicture(mSelectedImageFileUri!!,iv_user_photo)
                }catch (e:IOException){
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Toast.makeText(this@UserProfileActivity,resources.getString(R.string.image_selection_failed),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
        Log.e("Request Cancelled","Image selection cancelled")
    }
}

private fun validateUserProfileDetails(): Boolean{
    return when{
        TextUtils.isEmpty(et_phoneProfile.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }) -> {
            showErrorSnackBar(resources.getString(R.string.err_msg_enter_phoneNum),true)
            false
        }
        else ->{
            true
        }
    }
}

fun imageUploadSuccess(imageURL:String){
    //hideProgressDialog()

    mUserProfileImageURL = imageURL
    updateUserProfileDetails()
}
```

}

FirestoreClass.kt

```
class FirestoreClass {

private val mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

fun registerUser(activity: RegisterActivity, userInfo:User){
    mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS)
        //Document ID for users fields.Here the document it is the User ID.
        .document(userInfo.id)
        .set(userInfo, SetOptions.merge())
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            activity.userRegistrationSuccess()
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            activity.hideProgressDialog()
            Log.e(activity.javaClass.simpleName,"Error while registering the user.",e)
        }

}

fun getCurrentUserID(): String{
    //An Instance of currentUser using FirebaseAuth
    val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    //A variable to assign the currentUserId if it is not null or else it will be blank
    var currentUserID=""
    if(currentUser != null){
        currentUserID = currentUser.uid
    }
    return currentUserID
}

fun getUserDetails(activity: Activity){
    //Here we pass the collection name from which we wants the data.
    mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS)
        // The document id to get the Fields of user.
        .document(getCurrentUserID())
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            Log.i(activity.javaClass.simpleName,document.toString())

            val user = document.toObject(User::class.java)!!

            val sharedPreferences = activity.getSharedPreferences(Constants.MYSHOPPAL_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val editor : SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
            editor.putString(Constants.LOGGED_IN_USERNAME,"${user.username}")
            editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,"${user.email}")
            editor.apply()

            when(activity){
                is LoginActivity ->{
                    activity.userLoggedInSuccess(user)
                }
            }
            //END
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            when (activity){
                is LoginActivity ->{
                    activity.hideProgressDialog()
                }
            }

            Log.e(activity.javaClass.simpleName,"Error while getting user details",e)
        }
}

fun updateUserProfileData(activity: Activity,userHashMap: HashMap<String,Any>){
    mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS).document(getCurrentUserID())
        .update(userHashMap)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            when(activity){
                is UserProfileActivity -> {
                    activity.userProfileUpdateSuccess()
                }
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            when (activity){
                is UserProfileActivity -> {
                    //Hide the progress dialog if there is any error.And print the error in log.
                    activity.hideProgressDialog()
                }
            }
            Log.e(activity.javaClass.simpleName,"Error while updating the user details.",e)
        }
}

fun uploadImageToCloudStorage(activity:Activity,imageFileURI: Uri?){
    val sRef: StorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(
        Constants.USER_PROFILE_IMAGE + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." +Constants.getFileExtension(activity,imageFileURI)
    )

    sRef.putFile(imageFileURI!!).addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
        Log.e("Firebase Image URL",taskSnapshot.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl.toString())
        taskSnapshot.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl
            .addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                Log.e("Downloadable Image URL",uri.toString())
                when(activity){
                    is UserProfileActivity ->{
                        activity.imageUploadSuccess(uri.toString())
                    }
                }
            }
    }
        .addOnFailureListener{exception ->
            when (activity){
                is UserProfileActivity -> {
                    activity.hideProgressDialog()
                }
            }

            Log.e(activity.javaClass.simpleName,exception.message,exception)
        }

}
```

}

Constants.kt

```
object Constants {
const val USERS : String = "users"
const val MYSHOPPAL_PREFERENCES:String = "MyShopPalPrefs"
const val LOGGED_IN_USERNAME: String = "logged_in_username"
const val EXTRA_USER_DETAILS:String = "extra_user_details"
const val READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 2
const val PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 1

const val MALE:String = "Male"
const val FEMALE:String = "Female"
const val MOBILE:String = "mobile"
const val GENDER:String = "gender"
const val IMAGE:String = "image"
const val EMAIL:String ="email"
const val COMPLETE_PROFILE:String = "profileCompleted"
const val USER_PROFILE_IMAGE: String = "User_Profile_Image"

fun showImageChooser(activity : Activity){
    val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    activity.startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
}

fun getFileExtension(activity: Activity,uri: Uri?):String? {
    return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
        .getExtensionFromMimeType(activity.contentResolver.getType(uri!!))
}
```

}

Database structure
[image: Database structure]

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400 (four hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: What does `intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.EXTRA_USER_DETAILS)`?

Comment: get the user details from instant

Comment: ANd if log the value, is it what you want?

Comment: I think my problem is SettingsFragment cannot go to the UserProfileActivity when clicking the edit button. If LoginActivity->UserProfileActivity, it can work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `Activity` requires an `Intent` extra to initialize the `lateinit` property, but when you start the `Activity` from the `SettingsFragment` you don't seem to paas that extra in the `Intent`

`Intent` extra required in `Activity`

```
if(intent.hasExtra(Constants.EXTRA_USER_DETAILS)){
   // Get the user details from instant as a ParcelableExtra.
   mUserDetails = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.EXTRA_USER_DETAILS)!!
}
```

`Intent` extra not passed from `SettingsFragment`

```
root.iv_edit.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(requireContext(), UserProfileActivity::class.java)
    // Need to pass userDetails when starting UserProfileActivity
    // intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_USER_DETAILS, userDetails)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: Hi sir, so what can I do for the SettingsFragment?

Comment: you need to paas the user details in intent extra from `SettinsFragment`